# I want to output text I type backwards unless I type stop, recognize capital letters also need a solution without new char[string.length]

Tags: java, string, reverse

so the first part is easy!
i just ask to enter some text and reverse this string with the reverseString method.
it will ask as long as i enter stop.
it doesent work without the second if !.equals("stop") ?

```
`
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        while (!input.toLowerCase().equals("stop")) {
            System.out.println("Enter some text:");
            input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (!input.toLowerCase().equals("stop")) {
                String reversed = reverseString(input);
                System.out.println("Reversed: " + reversed);

                if (isPalindrome(input))
                    System.out.println("That's a palindrome!");
            }
        }
    }

///here is the second new char[string.length()] i dont get it; 

    public static String reverseString(String string) {
        int length = string.length();
        char[] reversed = new char[length];
        for (int i = 0, j = length - 1; i < length; i++, j--) {
            reversed[j] = string.charAt(i);
        }
        return new String(reversed);
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
        String normalized = normalizeString(string);
        return normalized.equals(reverseString(normalized));
    }

///here is the second new char[string.length()] i dont get it; 

    public static String normalizeString(String string) {
        char[] normalized = new char[string.length()];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            char c = string.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                normalized[count++] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            }
        }
        return new String(normalized, 0, count);
    }
}


`
```

I've tried so many things but I can't find a simple solution anymore without rewriting the whole code. are there too many methods? should i do something with substrings ? Maybe you have an idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to write this kind of a loop is using the `break` keyword.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter some text:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals("stop")) {
            break;
        }
        String reversed = reverseString(input);
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + reversed);
        if (isPalindrome(input))
            System.out.println("That's a palindrome!");
        }
    }
}
```

This eliminates the redundant test for special input, and makes your code more readable by reducing nesting.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... it doesent work without the second if !.equals("stop")"*

You'll need to re-order a few things for it to work with a single check for *"stop"*.

I suggest adding a *boolean* variable, to indicate when the loop should be exited.
And, change the *while* loop, to a *do-while* loop.

Additionally, you can use *[String#equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))* to equate strings with different cases.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
boolean exit = false;

do {
    System.out.println("Enter some text:");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) exit = true;
    else {
        String reversed = reverseString(input);
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + reversed);

        if (isPalindrome(input))
            System.out.println("That's a palindrome!");
    }
} while (!exit);
```

Everything else appears correct.

> *"... need a solution without new char[string.length]"*

There are a few ways to reverse a *String* value.

You can optimize your code, by using the following.

```java
public static String reverseString(String string) {
    String reversed = "";
    for (char character : string.toCharArray())
        reversed = character + reversed;
    return reversed;
}
```

Additionally, you can use the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* class, which has a *[reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())* method.

```java
public static String reverseString(String string) {
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(string);
    return reversed.reverse().toString();
}
```